# Do products like Redex work?

Tags: fuel-system, diesel, cleaning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are fuel system cleaners (like Gumout) worth using regularly?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/229/are-fuel-system-cleaners-like-gumout-worth-using-regularly)

Do products like Redex, which state that they "[help] to stop harmful deposits build up on the carburettor and in the fuel system, which can reduce the vehicle's performance", actually work?

More specifically, when one follows the directions and adds it to diesel (in my case) or petrol while filling up, is one just "burning money"?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean just their cleaning products? I use a Redex octane booster when I can't get suitable petrol - it really works but is probably not what you mean.

Comment: I believe the discussion that happened over here addresses this point nicely: http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/233/57  As-is, this question is hard to answer on it's own.  @CoryLarson's point that you need to determine your goals first is a good one.